# Silverlight Google Analytics Integration

Tags: silverlight, google-analytics

We have a Silverlight LOB that we need to integrate Google analytics. I have been exploring the Microsoft Silverlight Analytics Framework (MSAF) for the past few days. Unfortunately, I don’t get any response to many of my questions in the MSAF discussion forum. Now I'm forced to find a decent alternative to MSAF. I gave up MSAF due to the following reasons:

1. Not getting any answers to many of my questions
2. Not sure if MSAF support Google’s E-commerce tracking. If so how

Do you have any experience integrating Google analytics with Silverlight? Especially the e-commerce tracking part of it? Any inputs/links/resources in this regard will be very helpful. Sincerely appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a widget for blogengine.net to show total visits on the blog from Google Analytics. You need to use GData - Google Data API for this. Have a look at this widget. May be it is not of lot of help but at least it can get you started.
http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Blog-Analytics-Widget-For-BlogEngineNET-Powered-By-Google-Analytics.aspx